# MacroDroid extract last call from phone calls log

Tags: samsung, macrodroid

I would like to use MacroDroid to open the phone calls log and get the first number on the list (last call) and send an sms to that number.

Not sure how to access get that number.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have root access or can you setup localhost adb access on your device? It is possible to get call logs using a command.